# Magento 1.9 admin showing 403 forbidden error

Tags: magento-1.9

magento front part is working fine but magento admin panel showing 403 error.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /agluser on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.aglasiangranito.com Port 443
```

any suggestion or help is highly appreciated.

thnks

Answer (score 1):

go to your Database Management:

```
Open PhpMyAdmin
Go to your database
Click SQL
Run the following SQL Query

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Care to explain why your solution might work? Just posting some SQL queries that update core tables is not really helpful, even though this may solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me ended up being a change to ModSecurity to switch off rule ID 214540. Error was in error_log

Comment: hi @Sam Weiner, i got same error in error_log, how can i fix?